# Test if a given numeric is comprised in a set of intervals defined in a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe which includes 2 columns, let's say "left" and "right", which define intervals. I want to test if a given numeric "x" is part of any interval defined by the dataframe (if it is, it should be only once, those intervals don't overlap). Expected behaviour:

```
> df <- data.frame(id = c("A", "B", "C"), left = c(0, 50, 150), right = c(15, 78, 190))
> df
  id left right
1  A    0    15
2  B   50    78
3  C  150   190
> my_function(7)
TRUE
> my_function(20)
FALSE
```

So I did it this way, but it's terribly slow and I'm pretty sure this could be optimized:

```
my_function <- function(x) {
    test <- df %>% dplyr::rowwise() %>% dplyr::mutate(test = (x >= left) && (x <= right)) %>% ungroup()
    test <- test %>% filter(test == T)
    nrow(test) == 1
}
```

Then I'd be interested in getting the matching row in case the output is TRUE, but with the current function it'll take forever (the actual dataframe has ~5,000 rows, and I want to test/get coordinates for thousands of x values).

I found a library that manages interval objets but it seems it's tailored for time intervals. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple way with an example:

```
z <- 567 # single dummy value
left <- x1 <- seq(100, 900, 200)
right <- seq(200, 1000, 200)
df <- data.frame(left, right) # dummy intervals

lo <- z >= df$left
hi <- z <= df$right
check <- lo * hi
introw <- which(check == 1)
introw
3

z2 <- c(356, 934, 134, 597, 771) # vector of values to check
lo2 <- sapply(z2, function(x) x >= df$left)
hi2 <- sapply(z2, function(x) x <= df$right)
check2 <- lo2 * hi2
introws <- apply(check2, 2, function(x) which(x ==1))
introws #vector of intervals for each input value
introws
2 5 1 3 4
final <- cbind(value = z2, interval = introws)
final
     value interval
[1,]   356        2
[2,]   934        5
[3,]   134        1
[4,]   597        3
[5,]   771        4
```

Comment: It looks better indeed, though still a bit slow

```user  system elapsed 
 80.435   4.117  84.951 ```

Comment: I've vectorized my function, so I can get rid of the `rowwise()` and `ungroup()` calls. A lot faster now! Thanks

```user  system elapsed 
  0.260   0.026   0.290```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach using `between()`:

```
#Code
my_function <- function(x) {
  test <- df %>% dplyr::rowwise() %>%
    dplyr::mutate(test = between(x,left,right)) %>% ungroup()
  test <- test %>% filter(test == T)
  nrow(test) == 1
}
```

Comment: It's just as slow:    

```user  system elapsed 
125.149   4.637 130.022 ```

```user  system elapsed 
135.310   4.640 140.233 ```

Comment: @rioulan.  Re: "It's just as slow"  Why don't you try my answer and report back results.  Just plug in your own vectors for `df$left`, `df$right` and `z2`

Comment: Oh, your answer had disappeared